# Return Class after Remove?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is it possible to return a class immediately after it's removed by hover? So when you're no longer hovering, the class returns?

```
$("#all").hover(function() {
 $('.morenav').removeClass('active');
$(this).closest(".morenav").toggleClass("hovered")});

 $("#all").click(function() {

$(this).closest(".morenav").toggleClass("active") });
```

The way it's set up now, the active class doesn't come back when the element is no longer hovered. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clearly stated in [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hover/). You can try something like this. Hope it helps.

```
$("#all").hover(function() {
    $('.morenav').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest(".morenav").toggleClass("hovered")
    }, function() {
        $('.morenav').addClass('active');
    });
$("#all").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".morenav").toggleClass("active") 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#all").hover(function() {
    $('.morenav').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest(".morenav").toggleClass("hovered")
    }, function() {
        $('.morenav').addClass('active');
    });
$("#all").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".morenav").toggleClass("active") 
});
```